# Beautifulsoup - how to process each piece of text in xml, independently? replace_with destroys children

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I want to string-replace each piece of text once, and keep the tree structure.

For example, each string will be reversed:   abc > cba.

If I apply "replace_with()" to the/a parent node, it simply joins the nested texts, and flatten the parent element.

```
nodes = soup.find_all(['a','b'])
for node in nodes:
    rep = node.text[::-1]
    node.string.replace_with(rep)
```

input:

```
<xml>
<a>abc
    <b>def </b>
    ghi
        <a>jkl 
            <b>mno</b>
        jkl </a>
    ghi
    <b>def </b>
abc</a>
</xml>
```

output:

```
<xml> cba fed ihg    lkj ihg fed cbA </xml>
```

Moreover, in some cases (not shown here) the loop processed inner children, and re-processed them again at the parent, resulting in mixed results; e.g.

```
abc def abc > cba def cba
```

I'd like to find a way to retrieve each piece of text, and process it indepenetly.

how?

Comment: Have you tried updating `node.text`? E.g. `node.text = node.text[::-1]`

Comment: You also need to update `node.tail = node.tail[::-1]` If it isn’t empty (e.g. the final abc in your example)

Comment: that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find_all(text=True)` to find only text nodes and then process them.

For example:

```
txt = '''<xml>
<a>abc
    <b>def </b>
    ghi
        <a>jkl
            <b>mno</b>
        jkl </a>
    ghi
    <b>def </b>
abc</a>
</xml>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for t in soup.find_all(text=True):
    t.replace_with(t[::-1])

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<xml>
 <a>
  cba
  <b>
   fed
  </b>
  ihg
  <a>
   lkj
   <b>
    onm
   </b>
   lkj
  </a>
  ihg
  <b>
   fed
  </b>
  cba
 </a>
</xml>
```

Comment: Great.   (BTW,   "soup.find_all(['a','b'], text=True"    only finds  <b> nodes, not <a>'s in my example !  )